# ionic 2: How to implement a fixed top panel

Tags: ionic2

I need to display a video in a panel on top of a page. The video is selected in a scrolling ion-list below. I have tried ion-card but that scrolls up with the list. The code looks as follows where I am using an ion-card img instead of the video for test. Playing with the CSS (position:fixed) does not seen to help much.

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Lists</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card>
        <div id="fixedOnTop">
            <img src="img/adam.jpg"/>
            <ion-card-content>
                <h2 class="card-title">
                    Video Panel
                </h2>
            </ion-card-content>
        </div>
    <ion-list id="belowCard">
        <button ion-item *ngFor="#item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <img src={{item.icon}}>
            </ion-avatar>
            {{item.title}}
            <div class="item-note" item-right>
                {{item.note}}
            </div>
        </button>
    </ion-list>
    <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
        You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
    </div>

</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the ionic 2 document I found that the ion-toolbar is always at the top of the ion-content area. The ion-toolbar has a min-height of 50 set is the ionic css. I used a class to override the min-height to the size I needed. It worked very well. I inserted the video element inside the toolbar.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet example? I am currently experience an issue where the top panel is not fixed when the keyboard is open in ios.